# Access to AWS Instance for Third Party

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services

This is probably a basic question; however, I am wondering about it nonetheless.

We have an AWS instance which is new and will host a web application. We shall do the server maintenance ourselves. However, the developers of our app (3rd party) need initial access to the server to test and set up the application.

The question is how we should give them the access. Particularly, I am wondering if we should send them the SSH key or if there is another way. We have no reason not to trust these people and are mostly wondering about best practices.

Comment: Don't give them the SSH private key. Add *their* SSH public keys to the authorized_keys file.

Comment: I see. And when I they are done with the work, remove their key?

Comment: Yes - or simply comment it out.

Comment: I would also get the IP they will be connecting from and update the security group to allow only that IP, rather than opening SSH to the world.

Comment: Additionally you could put that machine in an isolated subnet so they can never access any other resources in your network by applying the correct routing tables.

Comment: You could give them access to the AWS web console and use AWS Systems Manager Session Manager, which is SSH via the AWS web Console. Create them an IAM user, revoke rights when required. It takes quite a few steps to get it going though. Whitelisting their ssh key is a better option, but this is another option.

Comment: Someone should probably mention that while there is a technical answer to this question, it should be a huge red flag to you if third party developers need access to your production servers to test or set up the application, rather than packaging it up so that you can deploy (and redeploy) it yourself.  Your servers should be disposable and you should be able to rebuild them at any time with minimal effort.

Comment: Thank you all for the useful comments. I am following the suggestion with whitelisting their public key for the duration of the work. Could someone tell me how I can test whether whitelisting had worked? I have their public key in a file called `~/.ssh/id_rsa-Proj.pub`. How can I log into the instance using this key? I tried `ssh ubuntu@xxx.xxx ...`, but that didn't work. However, I am able to log into this instance with MY private key. Should I somehow switch the default public key of my machine?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to provide ssh access. But another option is that your 3rd party provides you with a AMI and shares it with your AWS account so you can spin it up as a EC2 instance. That way they can prepare the server, save it as an AMI image for you to run in your AWS account and you never have to give them access to your AWS network (VPC).